# What will be the sum of $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\log\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right) $?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\log\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right) $=$\displaystyle \sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\log\left(\frac{n^2-1}{n^2}\right) $ how can I continue it?

Comment: thank you for your comment, I've edited the exercise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recognize that we have

$$\log\left(\frac{n^2-1}{n^2}\right)=\log(n^2-1)-\log(n^2)=\underbrace{\bigg[\log(n-1)-\log(n)\bigg]}_{a_n}-\underbrace{\bigg[\log(n)-\log(n+1)\bigg]}_{a_{n+1}}$$

Thus it is telescoping and

$$\sum_{n=k}^\infty\log\left(1-\frac1{n^2}\right)=a_k=\log(k-1)-\log(k)=\log\left(1-\frac1k\right)$$

Answer (score 8):

That (starting at $n=2$) is the logarithm of a telescopic product:
$$ \log\prod_{n\geq 2}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right) = \log\lim_{N\to+\infty}\prod_{n=2}^{N}\frac{(N-1)(N+1)}{N^2} $$
and:
$$ \lim_{N\to +\infty}\log\frac{N+1}{2N} = \color{red}{-\log 2}.$$

I am adding an extra approach in order to avoid a duplicate answer (sorry, Simply Beautiful Art).
We have
$$ \frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi z}=\prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right) $$
hence:
$$ \prod_{n\geq 2}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right) = \lim_{z\to 1}\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi z (1-z^2)} = \frac{1}{2} $$
by de L'Hopital's rule. In a similar way
$$ \sum_{n\geq 3}\log\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right) = \color{red}{\log\frac{2}{3}}=\log(2)-\log(3).$$

Comment: xD That overkill sine product!  (+1)